# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and displaying queries as they happen in real time

Tags: sql-server

Two years ago a SQL expert opened a SSMS and showed all queries as they were happening in real time. That way he saw which SQL statements were running fast and which took some time to be ran. I remember the queries to be displayed in a "CMD" look alike window. I can't remember if new queries were displayed at the top or were they shown at the bottom of the window.

For the past month I have been trying to figure out how he got this working. I looked everywhere in monitor, but I can't find anything similar to what he showed me than.

The results were similar to the "claymore eth miner window" ...

Can someone point me in the direction of getting this?

Comment: SQL Server **Profiler**, by any chance?? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: You can use extended events to monitor query performance :  https://www.sqlshack.com/using-sql-server-extended-events-to-monitor-query-performance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sp_whoisactive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive) to get the current running queries. It is very useful to see if currently there is blocking, locking, long running statements.

In order to get better picture of what was going on in the past, you can enable the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16). There are some predefined reports:

[image]

and various statistics and it is user friendly:

[image]